# Django version (2.0.7) urlpatterns syntax

Tags: django, django-urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('signIn', views.signIn, name='signin'),
    path('postsign', views.postsign, name='postsignin'),
```

**This is my urls.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
import pyrebase

config = {
    'apiKey': "API-KEY",
    'authDomain': "cpanel-99cff.firebaseapp.com",
    'databaseURL': "https://cpanel-99cff.firebaseio.com",
    'projectId': "PROJECT-ID",
    'storageBucket': "cpanel-99cff.appspot.com",
    'messagingSenderId': "SENDER-ID"
  }

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
auth = firebase.auth()

def signIn(request):
    return render(request,"signIn.html")
def postsign(request):

    return render(request,"welcom.html")
```

**This is my views.py**

But whenever I'm giving the command "python3 manage.py runserver" on terminal I'm getting the following error
[Page not found at/signin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWtkb.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>signIN</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <form action="/postsign/" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %} 
   Email:
   <input type="email" name="email">
   Password:
   <input type="password" name="password">
   <input type="submit" value="SignIn" >
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is my signIn.html which is in templates folder

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>welcome</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 {% csrf_token %} 
 Welcome
  

 </body>
</html>
```

This is my welcome.html which is also in the templates folder.

Comment: Note that you fetch the path in lowercase `login`, not `logIn`, nevertheless I think it is probably better *not* to include uppercase in the first place.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the suggestion. Fixed it yet still the same error that Page not found :(

Comment: what if you add a tailing slash `/` to the path?

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so so much